# Mysql - WHERE a list of keys is not in subselect

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(obt.oid) AS oid, o.borrower_email
FROM `order_borrower_tracker` obt 
LEFT JOIN `orders` o ON obt.oid=o.oid
WHERE obt.date_acknowledged_edelivery = 0 
AND 18 NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(new_status) AS new_status 
    FROM `order_status_history` 
    WHERE oid=obt.oid)
```

Which works, but now I need to update this query so that not only "18" is not in the subselect, but also several other numbers.... something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(obt.oid) AS oid, o.borrower_email
FROM `order_borrower_tracker` obt 
LEFT JOIN `orders` o ON obt.oid=o.oid
WHERE obt.date_acknowledged_edelivery = 0 
AND (18,27,29,41,53) NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(new_status) AS new_status 
    FROM `order_status_history` 
    WHERE oid=obt.oid)
```

but obviously "(18,27,29,41,53) NOT IN" doesn't work.

What is a good alternative to achieve this? Without typing ANDs for each number

Comment: There's no need for parens around the `obt.oid` expression in the SELECT list. That almost makes it look like `DISTINCT` is a function, but it's not. It's a keyword, and it applies to _all_ the expressions in the SELECT list, not just the first expression enclosed in parens. (That is, those parens have no effect, and removing those parens won't change anything. It's just odd to see an expression unnecessarily wrapped in parens and butted up against the DISTINCT keyword.) If there are two distinct values of `borrower_email` for a given `obt.oid`, both of those rows will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a trick with LEFT JOIN and IS NULL to find orders that don't have any records with listed statuses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(obt.oid) AS oid, o.borrower_email
FROM `order_borrower_tracker` obt 
LEFT JOIN `orders` o 
    ON obt.oid=o.oid
LEFT JOIN `order_status_history` h
    ON h.oid=obt.oid AND h.new_status IN (18,27,29,41,53)
WHERE obt.date_acknowledged_edelivery = 0 
AND h.oid IS NULL
```

Comment: +1. The anti-join pattern is the way to go. But I think OP wants to use `h.oid = obt.oid` in the join predicate (per the original query)... there may not be a matching `o.oid` due to the "outerness" of the `LEFT JOIN o`. (The "trick" with the anti-join is that the LEFT JOIN will return all rows along with "matching" rows, the `IS NULL` in the WHERE clause will discard any rows where a "match" was found, leaving only rows that didn't have a match.